# How do I disable the personal contact form option in the user edit form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-contact-form

I am a Drupal beginner. When users create their account, they have the option to have a personal contact form. Where do I go to disable that? It's not in permissions. It's not a bad option, but I know it will confuse the hell out of my site's users. It may even scare some away!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit admin/build/contact/settings in Drupal 6 or 5 you can untick "Enable personal contact form by default"

Answer (score 6):

Tested in Drupal 7.

Place the following in template.php of your theme. Change MYTHEME to your theme name.

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    $form['contact']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Notice that access is set to false, instead of being unset(), i.e. removed. That way we're not interfering with the flow of data.

Answer (score 2):

A personal contact form is not something you get by default in Drupal. There are modules that can do this, you have probably activated such a module. Check what modules you have activated at admin/build/settings.

If you want to disable this for regular users only you should instead check you permission settings.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the Contact module under 'Core - Optional'. Look through user permissions for anything related to 'contact' and uncheck it.

Personally recommend Webform to handle site wide contact forms. It will let you construct your form with a UI. Easiest way to get a Contact Us page.

Answer (score 2):

**Drupal 7**

All answers NOT remove the section for personal contact option displayed (D7) at "***user/%/edit***"

[image]

**For remove tab AND settings for Drupal 7:**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('user_profile_form' === $form_id) {
     $form['contact']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $menu_items = menu_get_item();
    if('user/%/edit' === $menu_items['path']){
         $variables['page']['content']['content']['content']['system_main']['contact']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

After:

[image]

Comment: My answer does remove the section for personal contact option displayed. Check the simplify module. It does exactly what you did here custom in form_alter.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6:

If you want to have the site-wide contact form enabled, but not even display the option for a personal contact form to your users you must follow these steps:

1. Create a custom module

   http://www.hankpalan.com/blog/drupal/make-custom-drupal-module
2. Add this code to your .module file:

   function your_module_name_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

   unset ($form['contact']);

   }

Comment: I'd advise using $form['contact']['#access'] = FALSE; instead of unset($form['contact']); to prevent it from interfering with the core.

Answer (score 0):

Either check what modules you have set on drupal, or check the settings for contact forms. I believe it has the option for site wide contact form and user contact form.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Contact permissions](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/contact_permissions/tree/contact_permissions.module).
It provides a permission:

> "Have a personal contact form" which allows
>   administrators to configure which roles get the ability to have a
>   "Personal contact form".

Also the [Simplify](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify) module has a separate option for that.